# Where Ubuntu get installed?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows

Hi i shrinked the hdd of my laptop in app 450 GB (it shows as Unallocated space in windows disk management tool)

when i started the Ubuntu 16.04 installation i selected "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager" but the installation process didn't ask about partition/location, but everything got installed successfully.

Where is my ubuntu installation?

Maybe i screw it up and i had to chose the last option "Something else" (where you can resize the partition etc...)

Thanks

Comment: Unallocated space is not a partition. And you cannot create partitions for Linux from Windows. Post this: `sudo parted -l`

Answer (score 1):

You can use you favourite partition manager to list available partitions which will include those belonging to the Ubuntu installation. Examples are:

- GNOME Disks
- KDE Partition Manager
- GParted

On the command line you can use

- `parted -l` and
- `lsblk -f`

both of which require super-user privileges to run (through `sudo`).